# Twig and Symfony2 - test if a number is even

Tags: symfony, if-statement, twig

I would like to create  a table with different color for each even row. For that, I created the css and I will have to check in my twig template if the iteration index is even or not.

```
{% if loop.index == "even" %}
```

But how to check if a number is even in twig? Thank you.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd - CSS is your friend.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Twig has a built in "even" test:

```
{% if (loop.index is even) %}

...your code here

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to use the "modulo" operator as follow :

```
{% if(loop.index%2 == 0) %}

...your code here

{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you, I just found another possibility by using divisibleby(2), which also works.

Answer (score 4):

I think a more cleaner way would be:

```
{{ loop.index is odd ? 'is-odd' : 'is-even' }}
```